# Finding k smallest elements in a minimum heap

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have a minimum heap of size n.
I want to find smallest k elements without changing the original min-heap.
Run-time should be theta(k^2).
I can use memory theta(k).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a pseducode example:

```
candidates.add((heap[heap.root],heap.root))
while len(result)<k:
  (min_value,i)=candidates.remove_min()
  result.append(min_value)
  l=heap.left_child(i)
  r=help.right_child(i)
  candidates.add((heap[l],l))
  candidates.add((heap[r],r))
```

It is assumed that the heap has indices, and you can retrieve the value at any index using `heap[index]`.  The index of the root, containing the minimum value, is `heap.root`. `candidates` is a secondary min heap, initially empty, containing pairs of values and heap indices.  The minimum values are stored in `result`, in order.

The loop executes k times. All operations are constant time except for `candidates.remove_min()` and `candidates.add()`, which are O(log(k)), so the total time is O(k*log(k)).

Comment: Why -1? You can't just put that without comment.

Comment: @estro: I believe it is even better than that with the use of a min heap to store the candidates.  I've added some explanation.